# Proof of Hyperbolic Functions

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, hyperbolic-functions

*Find the proof:*

￼
(a) Use the definitions

**cosh(x)= 1/2(ex +e^−x) , sinh(x)= 1/2(e^x − e^−x)**

to express **sinh(x + y)** and **cosh(x + y)** in terms of cosh(x), sinh(x), cosh(y) and sinh(y).

(b) Using the results of part (a) show that

**sinh(x + 1) − sinh(x) = (−1 + cosh 1) sinh(x) + sinh 1 cosh(x)**

**cosh(x + 1) − cosh(x) = (−1 + cosh 1) cosh(x) + sinh 1 sinh(x)**

Considering the answer from part (a) is 
sinh(x+y) = sinh(x)cosh(x) +cosh(x)sinh(y)
and
cosh(x+y)=cosh(x)cosh(y) +sinh(x)sinh(y)

(c)***Use the result of part (b) to express the following sums***

**Cn =cosh0+cosh1+cosh2+···coshn **
**Sn =sinh0+sinh1+sinh2+···sinhn**

in terms of just cosh(n + 1), sinh(n + 1) and cosh 1 (and possibly some numbers like 1, 2 etc.).

*** Considering i know how to show parts a and b how can you show the result to part (C)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly right. You subsititute $y=1$ into the compound $\cosh$ identity and everything should go easily from there.

For part (c),

Rearrange $\sinh(x + 1) − \sinh(x) = \left(−1 + \cosh(1)\right) \sinh(x) + \sinh(1) \cosh(x)$

to get: $\sinh(x + 1) = \sinh(x) + \left(−1 + \cosh(1)\right) \sinh(x) + \sinh(1) \cosh(x)$

$\sinh(0)=0$ and $\cosh(0)=1$

$\sinh(0 + 1) = \sinh(0) + \left(−1 + \cosh(1)\right) \sinh(0) + \sinh(1) \cosh(0)$

$\sinh(1) = 0 + \left(−1 + \cosh(1)\right) (0) + \sinh(1) (1)$

$\sinh(1) = \sinh(1)$ as you would expect!

$\sinh(1 + 1) = \sinh(1) + \left(−1 + \cosh(1)\right) \sinh(1) + \sinh(1) \cosh(1)$

$\sinh(2) = 2\cosh(1)\sinh(1)$

Comment: any ideas for cosh? @tomi